# Internal card reader not recognized on boot

Tags: boot, usb, sd-card

In 9/10 times, my internal card reader is not recognized when booting my pc. It's a desktop computer and the card reader is attached directly (internally) to the mainboard (Asus H81M-K) via 9-pin connector. The operating system is Windows 8.1.
However, the card reader is always recognized if I have a card inserted before I power up the PC.

I already installed a new card reader from a different manufacturer, but the behavior stays the same. 
I also tried several USB power settings in the BIOS / UEFI but they didn't change anything (perhaps they are only for the "external" USB ports).

What can I do to solve the problem?